# C# How to put " in String?

Tags: c#, string, escaping

I'm trying to make my program press the " (Shift + 2 in the UK) when a button is pressed, but I'm not sure how to as when I enter..

```
SendKeys.Send(""");
```

It converts the latter part of the code to string.

Is there a way to make the program ignore a particular character? I'm not really sure how to go about this.

I'm making an on screen keyboard if anyone is wondering.

Comment: Hmm, I did search but this didn't come up. I shall search better next time.

Answer (score 3):

Escape the `"`, like so:

```
SendKeys.Send("\"");
```

Or use a string literal:

```
SendKeys.Send(@"""");
```

String literals in C# are usually nicer to read, but in this case, you still need to *escape* the single quote in the string literal, by doubling it.

In fact this is an interesting example of the one approach vs. the other:

```
"\""   // 4 chars, not very readable
```

vs:

```
@"""""   // 5 chars: even LESS readable: pretty confusing what it means
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SendKeys.Send("\"");
```

Something like this should work.

Have a look at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx) (what you're looking for is called escaping characters)

Comment: And it did! Much obliged and thank you for the quick answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can use escape characters:

```
SendKeys.Send("\"");
```

The `\"` translates to just ".